# How to search for all SUID/SGID files?

Tags: find

All the howtos that I find on the web states:

```
Find all SUID files:
find / -perm -4000 -print
Find all SGID files:
find / -perm -2000 -print
```

But that is not true. See:

```
$ ls -lah test
-r-sr-xr-x  1 user  user     0B Jan 24 22:47 test
$ 
$ 
$ stat -x test | grep Mode
  Mode: (4555/-r-sr-xr-x)         Uid: ( 1000/    user)  Gid: ( 1000/    user)
$ 
$ 
$ find test -perm 4000
$ find test -perm 2000
$
```

**Question:** So what is the truth? How can I really list all the SUID/SGID files?

Comment: Uhm, so why exactly is this "not true"? You did *R*ead *T*he *F*riendly *M*anual, right? *File's permission bits are **exactly** mode (octal or symbolic).*

Comment: ** test**  is a file. Find searches on directories. So you should use find on the directory where test resides.

Comment: @Nils: untrue. `find` (GNU find to be exact) will take directories and files alike. He/she simply misses the point of the `-perm` switch. Reading the manual would help.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Interesting. My linux-manpage on CentOS 5 tells me it will only take directories. Is there much sense in running it on a file?

Comment: @Nils: nope there is no particular sense in doing it. But it won't you prevent from that folly. Regardless, at first glance I also thought this to be the issue. Alas, it isn't for this question. You can try by checking for some any bits on a file like this `find $FILE -perm /7777` to see whether your `find` does it or prevents it.

Comment: `find / -perm -4000` works on Mac. Use `sudo find / -perm +6000` to find all SUID or SGID files.

Comment: `-perm -mode` will match _all_ of the permission bits,
`-perm /mode` will match _any_ of the permission bits,
`-perm +mode` is deprecated in the latest `find`.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to test for **any** of the bits, use `/`. I.e. for your use case:

```
find "$DIRECTORY" -perm /4000
```

and:

```
find "$DIRECTORY" -perm /2000
```

or combined:

```
find "$DIRECTORY" -perm /6000
```

You may use both folders and files as argument for GNU `find`.

Another, IMO better readable, approach is using the mnemonic shortcuts. I.e.:

```
find "$DIRECTORY" -perm /u=s,g=s
```

#### Caveat emptor

Keep in mind that the variants of `find` vary. They may also behave differently. Always read the friendly manual (RTFM).

Answer (score 19):

By using the following command you can enumerate all binaries having SUID permission. The `-perm -u=s` flag of the `find` tool does the trick:

```
find / -perm -u=s -type f 2>/dev/null
```