# find files with peculiar permissions set

Tags: permissions, find, sticky-bit

I'm prepping for the LPIC1 exam, strongly relying on their online material [here](https://learning.lpi.org/en/learning-materials/102-500/).
Can someone pls help me clarify this doubt?

What is the difference among these:

1. `find ~ -perm 4000`
2. `find ~ -perm -4000`
3. `find ~ -perm /4000`

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/180867/117549

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213456/117549 ?

Comment: thanks @JeffSchaller , the 2nd link cleared it for me. It's respectively "exactly", "all" and "any" of the permissions set in files, as indicated by _the mode bits_ that follow the`-perm` switch.